# Use Realm data to fill the UITableView (table)?

Tags: objective-c, swift, multithreading, uitableview, realm

My solution which doesn't work - I get data with realm store it as array and reuse this array in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

The problem is I should get data in the background thread but fill the table in main thread.

Note: I have already read that if I get the realm data in current thread then I can use them in this thread only. Otherwise I should create `ThreadSafeReference` for each realm object I need and reuse it in main thread. But I can't understand how to do it - the example is written with such way that they create an object before `dispatch_async` and use it inside this object (like passing a variable into the code block).

In my case I have a separate array which I should store and reuse in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (which is not code block) and called multiple times. I also can't call `dispatch_async` with a thread I need inside it because the cell may become invalid.

How to solve this issue? Should I cache Realm objects manually? I accept both Swift and Objective-C languages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
// ViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MyObject.h" // subclass of RLMObject

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
@property RLMResults<MyObject *> *objectsList;

@end
```

And the implementation:

```
// ViewController.m
#import "MyViewController.h"

@implementation MyViewController {

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    _objectsList = [MyObject allObjects]; // optionally sort, query, etc.
}

- (void)viewDidAppear {
    [super viewDidAppear];
    // Do any other setup
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDataSource

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _objectsList.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Setup the cell with the object's information. It's up to you how 
    // to do it. Register a custom subclass of UITableViewCell, for example.
    MyObject *thisCellObject = [objectsList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.myTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"customIdentifier"];

    // Title should be a property on your MyObject class
    cell.textLabel.text = thisCellObject.title;
}

#pragma mark - UITableViewDelegate

// Implement the Delegate methods as you want it...
}
```

No need to invoke the Realm Objects from other threads of using Dispatch. The only case you'll get those "incorrect thread" errors would be if you pass a reference from you view controller to other class, like a background networking client or something similar.

Anyway those cases are avoidable too. If your objects got an ID, let's say from an API, you pass the ID to the other class, maybe the background sync client, and from that client perform a query for the object, like `[MyObject objectsWhere:@"objectID == %@", idString];`. The object is being called from the background process that will use it and therefore it's not going to fail.

Comment: `No need to invoke the Realm Objects from other threads of using Dispatch.` I hope you understand that Realm as database is not superfast. So in better case you get a delay before showing view controller, in worst case you get unpredictable behavior with warnings/errors because you slow down `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Realm is intended to be used as this answer describes. If you actually have a project that's experiencing this sort of slowdown behavior feel free to file a ticket against our GitHub (https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa) and we can either fix any bugs it reveals or help you figure out what you're doing wrong.